# failed to print using escpos-php

Tags: php, linux, printf

i try to print on my local linux server to my windows client with php using this library. https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php. when i am run it on xampp its work fine, but when i migrate my source to linux server, i have notice like this :

```
"smbclient '\/\/192.168.1.6\/debian_printer'
-c 'print -' -N\" failed with exit code 1: Domain=[T410] OS=[Windows 8    Pro    9200] Server=[Windows 8 Pro
```

6.2]tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME"

i have try print using terminal : echo "hello worldas" | smbclient '//192.168.1.6/debian_print' -c 'print -' -N

and it works. any same problem with me?

thanks for your response